# Instantiate all functions in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
util.py contains:
def add
def subtract

instantiate.py contains:
def instantiate
```

where instantiate does:

```
import util
def instantiate():
    add = util.add
    subtract = util.subtract
```

So I can skip typing `util` everytime I use a function and I can instantiate them all using one function?

I tried but I get

```
NameError: global name 'util' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just want to import those functions into the same namespace, you could do something like this:

```
from util import *
```

then you can write `add` and so on without prefixing it with that module

Comment: You rock! Thanks that seems to be easier

Comment: if you found one of the answers helpful, mark the question as 'answered'

Comment: large projects can be a bit harder to read if there are lots of these `:-)`

Answer (score 7):

You can import specific functions from a module :

```
from util import add, substract
```

Comment: I tried doing: 
    def instanciateAll():
 from util import countInstanceOf,getAllUnique,getUnique,flames,reverseWord,fstrip,palindrome

But still it says the same error, though I could use what you gave me. I could just save a text file somewhere then add a new function then paste it on the Python cmd. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method that adds/subtracts, you should use `operator.add` or `operator.sub`.

Comment: I was just using add and subtract as an example, plus my question is how can I eliminate the assigning of function names to var names so that I will skip using the name of the import when using the functions, thanks anyway! 
And yeah I know I should use relevant names ^^